# MongoDB Date Comparison Issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose I am trying to select data from my database based on a date. In my case any account that hasn't been accessed in over an hour.

I am not getting any results when running the query:

```
db.accounts.findOne( { "last_used": { "$lte": "2016-05-26T09:31:08.480Z" }} )
```

Here's my code:

**bin/App.js**

```
import AccountModel from '../Models/Account';

let lastHour = new Date();
lastHour.setHours(lastHour.getHours() - 1);

let query = {
    "last_used": {
       "$lte" : ISODate(lastHour)
    }
};

// Get account that was last used at least an hour ago
AccountModel.findOne(query, function(err, account) {
    if(err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log(account);
});
```

**Models/AccountModel.js**

```
import Mongoose from 'mongoose';

export default Mongoose.model( 'Account', new Mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  date_added: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  last_used: { type: Date, default: Date.now } }
));
```

**db.accounts.find()**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("574555d0348bc17a1ab67f2c"),
    "username" : "testuser",
    "email" : "testuser@mydomain.com",
    "password" : "SOMEHASH",
    "last_used" : ISODate("2016-05-24T08:13:41.080Z"),
    "date_added" : ISODate("2016-05-24T07:35:44.121Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The first query should be pulling the result above because it was last accessed over an hour ago.

Any ideas on were I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `new Date(lastHour)` in the find query ?

Comment: No need to wrap the JS date instance with `ISODate` as `new Date()` returns the current date as a Date object which supports the ISO date format, simply query with that date `let query = { "last_used": { "$lte": lastHour } };`

Comment: @chridam same problem, still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh dear, the reason it failed is because I forgot to open the connection. I must have deleted by mistake. `Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tenpenny');` ... works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code.

Instead of doing `ISOdate` you can use `moment().subtract()` of [moment.js subtract](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/). Which will be easier to do calculations.

```
import AccountModel from '../Models/Account';

var moment = require('moment');
let lastHour = moment().subtract(1, 'hour')

let query = {
    "last_used": {
   "$lte" : new Date(lastHour)
    }
};

 // Get account that was last used at least an hour ago
AccountModel.findOne(query, function(err, account) {
    if(err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log(account);
});
```

Comment: That also produces null. I was originally using `Date`. Also isn't `lastHour` already a Date object?

Comment: @love2node As mentioned earlier, no need to wrap the date object as it's already supported as an ISODate with JS. You may want to use momentjs library for easier date manipulations.

Comment: @chridam `Moment().subtract(1, 'hours')` is much better :) Although, still returning null. Real confusing.

Comment: Updated my answer with moment js code. You can try using this. Let me know, whether it worked or not @love2node

Comment: @titi23 Why are you using `new Data(lastHour)` if `lastHour` is already a Date object?

Comment: Souldn't `"$lte" : new Date(lastHour)` be `"$lte" : lastHour` or `"$lte" : Moment().subtract(1, 'hour')`?

Comment: `Moment().subtract(1, 'hour')` wont return you a proper date object, so you have to use `new Date()`.

Comment: `let lastHour = moment().subtract(1, 'hour').toDate(),  query = { "last_used": { "$lte": lastHour } };`

Comment: @chridam it's in a way same to use `toDate()` or `new Date()` I think. Or is there any difference?

Comment: I can confirm the following is working fine for me:`$lte : Moment().subtract(1, 'hours')` I don't need to convert it.

Comment: @love2node It's working seems. But it is safe to use new Date() I think. After that your wish. Use it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

For date comparison you can use following code.

```
let oneHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
let now = Date.now();
let comaparisonDate = new Date(now-oneHour );

let query = {
    "last_used": {
       "$lte" : comaparisonDate
    }
};
```